# How do I activate windows 8.1? (clean install on a pre-installed laptop)

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, windows-installation, reinstall, oem

I used the media creation tool kit to create a windows 8.1 pro boot dvd from Microsoft's website.

I booted off of it, wiped my drive and partitions, recreated the partitions, and proceeded with the install.

I have an Asus Q400A...I called Microsoft support and the guy told me that my product key was an OEM key good for 3 computers and for windows 8!

(To get through the 8.1 install I had used a generic key.)

How am I supposed to activate Windows now? I have a key, but it is OEM, and I think when I wiped the partition it got rid of any recovery partition that came with the Asus laptop.

I called Asus and he told me that I would have to pay them and send it in. I really do NOT want to do this.

Any suggestions? I just wanted a fresh install (I had already backed up my files on an external drive) AND I wanted that fresh install to NOT include asus bloatware.

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the Win8-key cannot be used to install Win8.1. You would have to install Win8 first and then upgrade to Win8.1. Or you can use the generic key, as pointed out by @Ramhound and afterwards enter your Win8 key to activate win8.1.

But here's another suggestion:
Win10 accepts Win7/8/8.1 keys directly. So I would suggest to directly migrate to Win10. That means, do a clean install of Win10 (media can be created with the Media Creation Tool for Win10 in the same way as you did for Win8) and then install Win10 using the Win8-key.

Important to note: Did you computer come with Win8Pro OEM or Win8Core OEM? Only if it was Win8Pro OEM you will be able to upgrade to Win10Pro. Otherwise you need to use Win10Home.

Comment: Edited according to your expertise...I'd suggest you provide the correct answer yourself though.

Answer (score -1):

As Manoj said, A Windows 8 key can not be used for activating Windows 8.1
Based on your situation,you could install Windows 8 first, then perform a upgrade.
Since Windows 10 is available now,you can upgrade to Windows 10 and activate it using Windows 8 product key.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10